# How to access files from shared storage in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, filepicker

I have a form where I need to attach a file from the phone. I have been looking for a file picker but it can only access images, not files like pdf, doc, docx, etc.
How to achieve this all in jetpack compose?

Answer (score 10):

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#open-file), it could be done with `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

In Compose it you need [`rememberLauncherForActivityResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/compose/package-summary#rememberLauncherForActivityResult(androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract,kotlin.Function1)) to do it:

```kotlin
var pickedImageUri by remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
    println("selected file URI ${it.data?.data}")
    pickedImageUri = it.data?.data
}
pickedImageUri?.let {
    Text(it.toString())
}
Button(
    onClick = {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            .apply {
                addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            }
        launcher.launch(intent)
    }
) {
    Text("Select")
}
```

Comment: yup got it ... worked for me .

Comment: @AdityaSinha If this solved your question, please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979/794244) using the checkmark under the votes counter